# create nested loop of doubles in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of Doubles looks like this:

```
[4354.36,4220.0,4356.41,4400.0,4369.74,4481.54,4601.03,4024.1,4436.41]
```

Now I want to create a nested list that looks like this:

```
[[4354.36,4220.0],[4356.41,4400.0],[4369.74,4481.54],[4601.03,4024.1],[4436.41,4856.25]]
```

Should I iterate over the list? And how is this possible in Haskell?

Comment: Do you know how to write any Haskell?  How about primitive recursive functions?  What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: `\n -> unfoldr $ \x -> case splitAt n x of { ([], []) -> Nothing; (a, b) -> Just (a,b) }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a library function to split a list into chunks like that, it's called "chunksOf" in the Data.List.Split package.

Try it out in GHCI:

```
import Data.List.Split  
chunksOf 2 [4354.36,4220.0,4356.41,4400.0,4369.74,4481.54,4601.03,4024.1,4436.41]
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you are learning, you should try implementing it yourself, like in poida's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

If you are new to haskell it would be worth having a go at implementing the function yourself, even if it was just as a learning exercise.

As a haskell beginner here's mine:

```
chunksOf2 :: [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf2 [] = []
chunksOf2 [x] = [[x]]
chunksOf2 (x:y:ys) = [x,y]:(chunksOf2 ys)
```

In a functional language, instead of iterating over a list with a `for`/`while` loop like you would in an imperative language, you would use recursion and higher order functions.

IMHO one reason for this is because once you've define a variable in a (pure) functional language you can't change its value.

[Learn you a haskell for great good](http://learnyouahaskell.com) is a good resource for learning haskell and has a page specifically on [recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion).

Comment: I'm currently doing an edX course on functional programming (using Haskell) and that is exactly the approach I would have used. Learn you a haskell is a great book.